# Ajax submit new form, not submitting values

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, forms

I have jQuery creating a form dynamically and adding it to the end of the page it then triggers a submit.

```
var downloadReportForm = $('<form id="report" action="ReportExcel.aspx" method="POST" />');
downloadReportForm.append(String.format('<input id="{0}" name="{0}" value="{1}" />', "customerGroupId", filter.CustomerGroupID));
$('form').after(downloadReportForm);
downloadReportForm.submit();
```

The problem is in the ReportExcel.aspx code behind, I don't get the value for the input.  I don't even see the key for it.  It simply isn't being posted.

I've tried GET and POST, and I've looked in the Request objects QueryString, Form, and Params lists.  Nothing.

I can't use $.Post() though, since I need the response to come back to this page, as the aspx returns an excel content type, with it's bytes, and I need the browser to open the download dialog.

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.format do not work in Javascript unless you have wrote your own method.

Try this

```
var downloadReportForm = $('<form id="report" action="ReportExcel.aspx" method="POST" />');
downloadReportForm.append('input', {id:"customerGroupId", name:"customerGroupId", value: filter.CustomerGroupID, type:"hidden"});
$('form').after(downloadReportForm);
downloadReportForm.submit();
```

Comment: I have String.format, it works.  It's part of M$ Ajax library

Comment: Ok, then try setting the type of the input field as hidden and submit.

Comment: I tried both, and if I do an `alert(downloadReportForm.html());` it shows no id, name or value.  With String.format I had valid html.

Comment: And now, strangely, things have started working when I went back to the code I had.

Comment: Thats great..sometimes you have to take a break :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is using ajaxForm plug-in. visit http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
there is a lot of example using this plug-in.